# Why does std::thread take function to run by rvalue?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

There is one thing about `std::thread` which I don't understand:
why the constructor of `std::thread` takes function to run by rvalue?

I usually want to run a Functor with some members to another thread. Like this:

```
struct Function
{
    void operator() ( /* some args */)
    {
        /* some code */
    }

    /* some members */
}


void run_thread()
{
    Functor f( /* some data */);
    std::thread thread(f, /* some data */);

    /* do something and wait for thread to finish */
}
```

With current implementation of `std::thread` I must be sure my object is implementing move semantics. I don't get why cannot I pass it by reference.

Extra question is: what does it mean to refer to function by rvalue? Lambda expression?

Comment: `std::thread`'s constructor takes its function by forwarding reference.

Comment: Your object does not need to implement move semantics. If moving is not supported it just resorts to copying.

Comment: @nwp: what in case, when the object has deleted copy constructor? Why the copy is needed?

Comment: [Read you some Scott Meyers for great good!](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers).

Comment: Use a `std::reference_wrapper` to pass by reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your run_thread method `f` is an auto variable.  That means at the bottom of the scope `f` will be destroyed.  You claim that you will "wait for the thread to finish" but the compiler/runtime system does not know that!   It has to assume that `f` will be deleted, possibly before the thread that is supposed to call its method has a chance to start.

By copying (or moving) the `f`, the run time system gains control of the lifetime of its copy of `f` and can avoid some really nasty, hard to debug problems.

Answer (score 3):

`std::reference_wrapper` will expose an `operator()` to the wrapped object.  If you are willing to do the manual lifetime maintenance, `std::thread t(std::ref(f));` will run `f` by reference.

Of course in your code, this induces undefined behaviour as you did not manage lifetimes properly.

---

Finally, note that raw `thread` is a poor "client code" tool.  `async` is a touch better, but really you want a task queue with `packaged_task`s and `future`s and condition variables.  C++11 added enough threading support to write a decent threading system, but it provides primitives, not good "client code" tools.

In a toy program it may be enough.